# FXML Exception in JavaFx | TableView - Table is Null | Eclispe IDE

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, xampp, fxmlloader, fileloadexception

I have been working on it for the past 3-4 days. I have googled it and also saw similar questions' answers but it did not help me.

```
Exception at Changing Scence:javafx.fxml.LoadException:

address-to-//application/Dashboard.fxml
```

This is the Exception I am getting when I log into the dashboard from the login page. Usually, I am not getting this exception but when I am trying to display the data in tableView from the xampp server then this exception occurs otherwise it is working fine.

here is the code of Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
        private static Stage stg;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {
        
        stg = primaryStage;

        try {
            
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Login.fxml"));
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("My Application Title");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root , 1200,670));
        primaryStage.show();
        
        }catch(Exception e) {
            
            System.out.println("Exception Occured: " +e);
        }
    }
    
    //to change the scene
    public void changeScene(String fxml) {
        //passing XML file via a string parameter
        try {
        Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
        stg.getScene().setRoot(pane);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception at Changing Scence:" +e);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        launch(args);
    
    }
}
```

and this is the code on the login button

```
/*TO CHECK THE LOGIN 
     * CREDENTIALS STARTS*/
    @FXML
    public void loginUser(ActionEvent event) {
        
        uname = username.getText().toString();
        upass = password.getText().toString();
        
         try {
            DbConnectivity db = new DbConnectivity(); 
            pst = db.connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM adminlogin WHERE admin=? AND password=?");
            pst.setString(1, uname);
            pst.setString(2, upass);
            
            rst = pst.executeQuery();
            
        if(uname.isEmpty() && upass.isEmpty()) {
            
            wronginput.setText("Please Enter Credentials!");
         
        } else if(rst.next()) {
            
                wronginput.setText("Log In Success!");
                Main main = new Main();
                main.changeScene("/application/Dashboard.fxml");
                
            } else {
                
                wronginput.setText("Wrong Username or Password");
                username.setText("");
                password.setText("");
                username.requestFocus();
                
            }
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            System.out.println("Prepared Exception: "+e);
        }
         

    }
    /*TO CHECK LOGIN 
     * CREDENTIALS ENDS*/
```

And these are StackTrace

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
address-to-/application/Dashboard.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2714)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2555)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3368)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3292)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3264)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3240)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3233)
    at application.Main.changeScene(Main.java:39)
    at application.LoginControl.loginUser(LoginControl.java:59)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1852)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8923)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3894)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TableView.setItems(javafx.collections.ObservableList)" because "this.studentTable" is null
    at application.DashboardController.RefreshStudentRecord(DashboardController.java:343)
    at application.DashboardController.loadData(DashboardController.java:289)
    at application.DashboardController.initialize(DashboardController.java:281)
    at javafx.fxml@19.0.2.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2662)
    ... 66 more
```

For more clarifications

I have DashboardController.java that is implementing Initializable class.
Inside the controller class I have method to implement called initialize.
here is this method

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        loadData();
        
    }
```

In this method I am using loadData() method that is

```
private void loadData() {
        DbConnectivity db = new DbConnectivity();
        conn = db.getConnection();
        
        RefreshStudentRecord();
        
        stsno.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stsno"));
        stsname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stsname"));
        stsfname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stsfname"));
        stsid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stsid"));
        stscnic.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stscnic"));
        stsphone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stsphone"));
        stsaddress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stsaddress"));
        stsclass.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stsclass"));
    }
```

Inside the loadData() method I am calling another method that is

```
@FXML
    public void RefreshStudentRecord() {

         studentDataList.clear();
         studentquery = "SELECT * FROM studentdata";
         
         try {
            studentPst = conn.prepareStatement(studentquery);
            studentRst = studentPst.executeQuery();
            
            while(studentRst.next()) {
                studentDataList.add(new StudentsDataController(
                        studentRst.getInt("S_NO"),
                        studentRst.getString("studentname"),
                        studentRst.getString("fathername"),
                        studentRst.getString("studentid"),
                        studentRst.getString("studentcnic"),
                        studentRst.getString("phone"),
                        studentRst.getString("address"),
                        studentRst.getString("class")
                        )
                        );
                studentTable.setItems(studentDataList);
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception at Refresing student data: "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         
        }
```

I think the problem is somewhere thereby, seeing the StackTrace as it is pointing out that the table is null that's why all of the problems have occurred, but I have no clue why the table is null.

Kindly help me to solve this problem

Comment: .. and make sure the complete stacktrace is formatted as code (4 leading spaces ... which seem to lost somewhere near the end :)

Answer (score -1):

Before setting the table ArrayList, do a check to check if the ArrayList has some data. Also, move your studentTable.setItems outside the loop such that it looks as follows:

```
            while(studentRst.next()) {
            studentDataList.add(new StudentsDataController(
                    studentRst.getInt("S_NO"),
                    studentRst.getString("studentname"),
                    studentRst.getString("fathername"),
                    studentRst.getString("studentid"),
                    studentRst.getString("studentcnic"),
                    studentRst.getString("phone"),
                    studentRst.getString("address"),
                    studentRst.getString("class")
                    )
                    );
        }
if(studentDataList.size()>0){
            studentTable.setItems(studentDataList);
}
```

Comment: Still getting the NullPointerException for studentTable

Comment: So, it means that studentDataList is null not the studentTable. Now, is there any problem with the database or in retrieving the data from the database?

Comment: How would this help? If `studentTable` is not correctly injected in the original code, it is not going to be injected in this code either.

Comment: @SarmadAli *"it means that studentDataList is null not the studentTable"*. Huh? Your stack trace clearly states that `studentTable` is null.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all for taking interest in my Question.

Here is how I solved it.

I created a separate class to handle the stuff for the tableView and made this class the controller of the fxml of tableView.
Then everything went right :)

Comment: happy you fixed your problem, but .. well .. and as-are, neither question nor answer are not overly helpful to future readers.